# React native + redux populate store with data before any Component render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to react native + redux. I have an react native application where user first screen is login and after login am showing page of list of categories from server. To fetch list of categories need to pass authentication token, which we gets from login screen or either if he logged in previously then from AsyncStorage.

So before redering any component, I am creating store and manully dispatching fetchProfile() Action like this.

```
const store = createStore(reducer);
store.dispatch(fetchProfile());
```

So fetchProfile() try to reads profile data from AsyncStorage and dispatch action with data.

```
  export function fetchProfile() {
    return dispatch => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('@myapp:profile')
        .then((profileString) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_PROFILE',
            profile: profileString ? JSON.parse(profileString) :  {}
          })
        })
    }
  }
```

so before store get populated, login page get rendered. So using react-redux's connect method I am subscribing to store changes and loading login page conditionally.

```
 class MyApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
      if(this.props.profile)
        if(this.props.profile.authentication_token)
          retunr (<Home />);
    else
          return (<Login />);
      else
        return (<Loading />);
    }
  }

  import { connect } from 'react-redux';

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      profile: state.profile
    }
  }

  module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(MyApp);
```

So first 'Loading' component get rendered and when store is populated then either 'Login' or 'Home' component get rendered. So is it a correct flow? Or is there a way where I can get store populated first before any compnent render and instead of rendering 'Loading' component I can directly render 'Login' or 'Home' Component.

Answer (score 2):

Verry common approach is to have 3 actions for an async operation

**types.js**

```
export const FETCH_PROFILE_REQUEST = 'FETCH_PROFILE_REQUEST';
export const FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL = 'FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL';
```

**actions.js**

```
import * as types from './types';

export function fetchProfile() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.FETCH_PROFILE_REQUEST
    });
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@myapp:profile')
      .then((profileString) => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS,
          data: profileString ? JSON.parse(profileString) :  {}
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.FETCH_PROFILE_ERROR,
          error
        });
      });
  };
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import * as types from './types';

const isFetching = (state = false, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_PROFILE_REQUEST:
      return true;
    case types.FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
    case types.FETCH_PROFILE_FAIL:
      return false;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const data = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.FETCH_PROFILE_SUCCESS:
      return action.data;
  }
  return state;
};

export default combineReducers({
  isFetching,
  data
});
```

So you can get `isFetching` prop in your component and show/hide Loader component

Comment: Code in above question is doing same thing, but just want to make sure is it  I am doing it right way? Since store gets populated after rending. So rendering happens first ( till Loading component ) then Store get populated by fetchProfile which triggers re-rendering and then goes to Login or Home. So it is possible to pre-populate store data from AsyncStorage before any component render.

Comment: It is possible but then you'll show user a blank screen. If you have an async action usually it's much better to let user know that the app is loading and show `Loader` component. So you chose a right approach. I just refactored your code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can load all your data during the splash screen and then load the others screens after that. I did it like this. Hope it helps

```
class Root extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            store: configureStore( async () => {

                const user = this.state.store.getState().user || null;

                if (categories && categories.list.length < 1) {
                    this.state.store.dispatch(categoriesAction());
                }
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false
                });

            }, initialState)
        };
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <SplashScreen/>;
        }
        return (
            <Provider store={this.state.store}>
                <AppWithNavigationState />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux and Redux Persist (https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)  will solve your problem.
Don't make them complex.